# JavaScript and third party cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain

Say there is a site `foo.com` which loads JavaScript from site `bar.com`. Now, say the JavaScript from site `bar.com` tries to read cookies using `document.cookies`. I was under the impression that using JavaScript, you can read all the cookies set in the browser irrespective of their source. But it turns out that the JavaScript from the site `bar.com` can only access cookies set by `bar.com` and not any other. If this is the case, how are script injection attacks which steal cookies carried out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> But it turns out that the JavaScript from the site bar.com can only access cookies set by bar.com and not any other.

That isn't true. What matters is where the HTML document containing the `<script>` element is, not the URL of the JS file that said `<script>` mentions in the src attribute.

I suspect your problem is that you are accessing `document.cookies` when the property is called `document.cookie` (**Singular!**)

Comment: That's also how CDNs work, like the jQuery script that is loaded on this site: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js` doesn't live on domain `stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: @David, cookie thing was a spelling mistake while typing the question. I just now tried with alert(document.cookie) and I just get a blank string in spite of cookies being set. I am pretty baffled.

Comment: I performed a test. The domain makes no different. Perhaps the cookies you are trying to fetch are on a different path, or set to be HTTP only.

Comment: Cooke is not http only. Site foo.com contains script from site moo.bar.com and the cookie is set with domain bar.com(not moo.bar.com) with the path being /. This is the scenario I am testing and I am not able to read the cookies.

Comment: Then that is the problem. The script is running on foo.com so it can't read the cookie from bar.com — exactly as my answer said.

Comment: Err? Yes. It is a bar.com cookie, it gets included in all requests to bar.com, including subdomains. You can't read it with a script where the script element is in an HTML document on foo.com.

Comment: Oops. Got it. In cookie stealing it is the other way round. Script from bar.com residing in foo.com tries to read cookies from foo.com itself and not from bar.com. Thanks. Plugged the hole in my understanding.

Answer (score 5):

They load scripts *inside* the attacked page.

For instance, when comments in a blog system get compromised, they contain a `script` element that is executed when the page is rendered. This script can get the cookies and send it to the attacker's server.

That's why you should **never** trust user input and disallow at least certain tags in comments (or translate every `<` to `&lt;`). But don't do this on the client side, as this prevention technique can easily be circumvented; test for (and change) malicious input on the server side.

Answer (score 3):

You can only access cookies which have been set for the given domain name. From the [Wikipedia article on cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie):

> Beside the name/value pair, a cookie
>   may also contain an expiration date, a
>   path, a domain name, and whether the
>   cookie is intended only for encrypted
>   connections. RFC 2965 mandates cookies
>   have a version number, but this is
>   usually omitted. These pieces of data
>   follow the name=newvalue pair and are
>   separated by semicolons. For example,
>   a cookie can be created by the server
>   by sending a line Set-Cookie:
>   name=newvalue; expires=date; path=/;
>   domain=.example.org.
>
> The domain and
>   path tell the browser that the cookie
>   has to be sent back to the server when
>   requesting URLs of a given domain and
>   path. If not specified, they default
>   to the domain and path of the object
>   that was requested. As a result, the
>   domain and path strings may tell the
>   browser to send the cookie when it
>   normally would not. For security
>   reasons, the cookie is accepted only
>   if the server is a member of the
>   domain specified by the domain string.

If `foo.com` sent a cookie which had the domain name of `bar.com`, or even `.com`, then JavaSCript code on `bar.com` could read that cookie. However most browsers are configured to only accept cookies when the domain name matches, and would reject such a cookie.

Comment: I verified that the cookie is present but JavaScript is not able to read it.